# Recursion Schemes for Static Analysis (AST)

Tags: pl.programming-languages, recursion, se.software-engineering

In the process of creating an AST analysis framework one of the challenges is creating good reusable functions and to avoid too much boiler-plate code. To that end catamorphisms seem like a good fit, as described here:

[Catamorphisms (1-7)](http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/05/catamorphisms-part-one/)

Is there other interesting recursion schemes and techniques that are beneficial for AST analysis like catamorphisms?

In particular with application within the constraints of the F# programming language.

Comment: Paramorphisms, hylomorphisms, anamorphisms, .... Also look at some of the work by Ralf Lämmel on "Scrap your boilerplate".

Comment: Maybe the acronym AST is clear from context to experts. What does it mean here? (I would assume Abstract Syntax Tree). The paper "Parsing with Derivatives" might interest you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Yes, AST means what you think it means.